# Custom cell doesn't reload UI after tableview reloadData called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom cell. In the cell, I have a UILabel

```
    lazy var profileInfo: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textColor = turnOn ? .white : .black
    return label
}()
```

I have a UserDefaults boolean named turnOn to determine the label color. In my tableView Controller, I have a button to change the boolean value and then, calls tableView.reloadData(). However, my label doesn't change the color when tableView.reloadData() runs. I have to quit the app and run it again to see the effect. My question are does tableView reload data the right method to use? and is there a way to handle this situation? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your `change turnOn` code?

Comment: If you expect this change to occur at `label.textColor = turnOn ? .white : .black` it's never going to happen. As written, the code to create your `profileInfo` instance is executed only once.

Comment: @GregoryHigley I see. Before I thought my UI will refresh also with tableView.reloadData(). It's good to know

Comment: @KevinVuD See Suhit Patil's answer. It is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the point of lazy properties is that they are computed only when they are first needed, after which their value is saved.

If you take out code to set `label.textColor` outside of lazy block, then it should work properly. Call configureCell function from cellForRow method and do the configuration part there.

```
func configureCell() {
  label.textColor = turnOn ? .white : .black
}
```

Comment: so for all the UI changes, I need to do it in cellForRow instead of inside the custom cell class, right?

Comment: You need to do it in a code path that executes when the cell is reloaded. But since you're obviously new to this, yes, do it in `cellForRow`.

Comment: add configureCell function in your custom cell and call from cellForRow like cell.configureCell(). Not sure where is your turnOn switch is executed if its the same cell then you can call on change of turnOn as well to save the reloadData part.

Comment: Thank you very much